# Move search form right after top menu in Magento 2.2

Tags: layout, magento2.2, forms, search

How to move mini search form after header menu? I am using

```
<move element="top.search" destination="catalog.topnav" after="-"/>
```

to achieve this but no success.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code

```
    <body>
    <move element="top.search" destination="page.top" after="navigation.sections"/>
    OR As you need
    <move element="top.search" destination="page.top" after="catalog.topnav"/>


    ....
    </body>
```

run below commands

```
php bin/magento cache:clean && php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Comment: Greate. That's work.

Comment: good, if your problem solved then please accept this answer

Comment: First line "after="navigation-sections"" works for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
<move element="top.search" destination="page.top" after="catalog.topnav"/>
```

you are **catalog.topnav** as destination which is not a container but it is a block.

Comment: I tried you code but it shows search form after banner slider of my home page.

Comment: Ok, It works for blank and luma theme, if it doesn't work, you may use navigation-sections as a value of after argument